# C# equivalent of a javascript TypedArray created from an existing array's .buffer?

Tags: javascript, c#, typedarray

I am trying to convert a javascript function to a C# script. One of the things the javascript version does is create a Uint32Array from an existing Float32Array's .buffer

Does anyone know what the equivalent of this would be in C#? I am NOT talking about what Float32Array and Uint32Array are in C# I am talking about the way that the javascript typed array gets initialized using the buffer from the dst variable (see code)... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray Its important because other arrays get initialized later on after this function using (for example) var dstUint32 = new Uint32Array(dst.buffer)...

This is the code (src is an existing Float32Array - see a bit of the initial values for this below)...

```
compileClassifier = function(src, width, scale, dst) {
        width += 1;
        if (!dst) dst = new Float32Array(src.length);
        var dstUint32 = new Uint32Array(dst.buffer);

        dstUint32[0] = src[0];
        dstUint32[1] = src[1];
        var dstIndex = 1;
        for (var srcIndex = 1, iEnd = src.length - 1; srcIndex < iEnd; ) {
            dst[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];

            var numComplexClassifiers = dstUint32[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];
            for (var j = 0, jEnd = numComplexClassifiers; j < jEnd; ++j) {

                var tilted = dst[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];
                var numFeaturesTimes3 = dstUint32[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex] * 3;
                if (tilted) {
                    for (var kEnd = dstIndex + numFeaturesTimes3; dstIndex < kEnd; ) {
                        dstUint32[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex] + src[++srcIndex] * width;
                        dstUint32[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex] * (width + 1) + ((src[++srcIndex] * (width - 1)) << 16);
                        dst[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var kEnd = dstIndex + numFeaturesTimes3; dstIndex < kEnd; ) {
                        dstUint32[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex] + src[++srcIndex] * width;
                        dstUint32[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex] + ((src[++srcIndex] * width) << 16);
                        dst[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];
                    }
                }

                var inverseClassifierThreshold = 1 / src[++srcIndex];
                for (var k = 0; k < numFeaturesTimes3; ) {
                    dst[dstIndex - k] *= inverseClassifierThreshold;
                    k += 3;
                }

                if (inverseClassifierThreshold < 0) {
                    dst[dstIndex + 2] = src[++srcIndex];
                    dst[dstIndex + 1] = src[++srcIndex];
                    dstIndex += 2;
                } else {
                    dst[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];
                    dst[++dstIndex] = src[++srcIndex];
                }
            }
        }
        dst = dst.subarray(0, dstIndex + 1);
        return dst;
    }
```

The src variable in there is created from this (this is a very cut down version the full version is thousands of numbers long):-

```
var classifier = [20,20,0.8226894140243530,3,0,2,3,7,14,4,-1.,3,9,14,2,2.,4.0141958743333817e-003,0.0337941907346249,0.8378106951713562,0,2,1,2,18,4,-1.,7,2,6,4,3.,0.0151513395830989,0.1514132022857666,0.7488812208175659,0,2,1,7,15,9,-1.,1,10,15,3,3.,4.2109931819140911e-003,0.0900492817163467,0.6374819874763489,6.9566087722778320,16,0,2,5,6,2,6,-1.,5,9,2,3,2.,1.6227109590545297e-003,0.0693085864186287];
src = new Float32Array(classifier);
```

This is what gets logged in the console for dstUint32 and dst respectively with those numbers set as src (the function doesn't work with just those numbers since as I say the actual array is far, far longer) Its interesting that almost none of the numbers match the original array...

```
[20, 20, 1062378438, 3, 0, 6, 1641, 61341710, 3279494571, 2109, 30670862, 1140399531, 1024093127, 1062632131, 0, 6, 469, 61341714, 3263430756, 475, 61341702, 1128661142, 1041959952, 1061140142, 0, 6, 1639, 138018831, 3278731586, 2341, 46006287, 1144134386, 1035496386, 1059271173, 1088330890, 16, 0, 6, 1409, 92012546, 3290042412, 2111, 46006274, 1150947372, 1032712617, 4294967295, 4294967295, 0, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 0, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 0, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 0, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 0, 4294967295]


[2.802596928649634e-44, 2.802596928649634e-44, 0.822689414024353, 4.203895392974451e-45, 0, 8.407790785948902e-45, 2.2995307799570248e-42, 9.874165102541455e-37, -249.1158905029297, 2.955338461261039e-42, 7.787657921469055e-38, 498.2317810058594, 0.03379419073462486, 0.8378106951713562, 0, 8.407790785948902e-45, 6.572089797683392e-43, 9.874168689865524e-37, -66.00076293945312, 6.656167705542881e-43, 9.874157927893318e-37, 198.00228881835938, 0.1514132022857666, 0.7488812208175659, 0, 8.407790785948902e-45, 2.2967281830283752e-42, 5.597240788537616e-34, -237.47366333007812, 3.280439704984397e-42, 2.7918024463192472e-37, 712.4210205078125, 0.09004928171634674, 0.6374819874763489, 6.956608772277832, 2.2420775429197073e-44, 0, 8.407790785948902e-45, 1.9744295362336673e-42, 1.1848984491218286e-35, -616.252685546875, 2.958141058189689e-42, 2.7917995316184414e-37, 1232.50537109375, 0.06930858641862869, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN]
```

So you can see here that the code

```
dstUint32[0] = src[0];
dstUint32[1] = src[1];
```

appears to have set BOTH dstUint32[0]/dstUint32[1] AND dst[0]/dst[1] to something, just that in dst[0]/dst[1] the value is getting logged as 2.802596928649634e-44 rather than 20?

Comment: A `Float32Array` in C# is a `float[]`

Comment: And a `UInt32Array` in C# would be a `uint[]`.

Comment: The rest of the code should be mostly the same. Except that you'll have to cast a `float` to `uint`.

Comment: @ MikeC I tried creating the array as an untyped array in C# (var test = new[]{20,20,0.8226894140243530,3,0,2,3,7,14,4,-1.0,3,9,14,2,2.0,4.0141958743333817e-003, etc) and its type got set to double, if I then do float[] floatTest = Array.ConvertAll(test, x => (float) x); the values are much shorter (i.e. 0.822689414024353 becomes 0.8226894) so I think maybe its double[]?

Comment: That's not an untyped array. `var` is replaced and inferred at compile time. You really have `double[] test`. If you want floats and to still use `var`, you need to specify each number with the float literal of `F` or define your array as `new float[]{...}`.. Example: `var test = new[] {20F, 20F, 0.8226F....}`.

Comment: The other thing, as you can see from the console, is that dst and dstUint32 seem to be affecting the same data (i.e. var dstUint32 = new Uint32Array(dst.buffer); actually seems to create a reference to dst's data but modifies it using int values - or something like that- so somehow 2.802596928649634e-44 in dst is the same as 20 in dstUint32)...

Comment: @TyCobb sorry I meant 'Implicitly typed' as described  here... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx its not important- I just did it to see what type it ended up getting logged as

Comment: So just to re-iterate, its mainly the way that the javascript typed array gets initialized using the buffer from dst that I cant gt my head around... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray
Its important because other arrays get initialized later on using (for example) var dstUint32 = new Uint32Array(dst.buffer)...

Comment: I believe the initialization you speak of is creating a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) so you're correct in thinking that dstUInt32 is essentially converting <native buffer format> to and from <int>,

Answer (score 7):

- The equivalent of a js `UInt32Array` is `UInt32[]`.
- The equivalent of a js `Float32Array` is `float[]`.
- The equivalent of an `ArrayBuffer` is `byte[]`.

JavaScript typed arrays are **views** onto the array buffer. Thus the element in the UInt32Array is not *cast* to a float, rather the contents of the physical storage - the bits - are *reinterpreted* as a float.

To do this in C# you need to do one of a couple of things.

**If you care about sharing the arraybuffer**

If you care about sharing the arraybuffer, i.e. you need change in one array to show up in the other array immediately, then you need to implement the whole thing. C# doesn't offer this out of the box. In order to achieve it you will need to use the `InteropServices.Marshal` facilities. These will allow you to get access to the underlying memory.

**If you don't care about sharing the arraybuffer**

If you just want to convert in one direction, then maybe later convert back again, but you don't need changes to be visible immediately, or to use a shared ArrayBuffer, you have an easier job.

- Create a MemoryStream,
- write the Float32 elements from the array
- read the UInt32 elements

Something like this:

```
    static byte[] ReinterpretAsByteArray(UInt32[] a)
    {
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(s, Encoding.Unicode, true))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                {
                    w.Write(a[i]);
                }
            }
            return s.ToArray();
        }
    }
    static float[] ReinterpretAsFloatArray(byte[] b) {
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(b, false)) {
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s, Encoding.Unicode, true))
            {
                float[] f = new float[b.Length / 4]; // 4 = sizeof float
                for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
                {
                    f[i] = r.ReadSingle();
                }
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need to write a similar function to convert a byte array to a Uint32 array, and to convert a float array to a byte array, but that is a matter of changing two lines.

Comment: Please name your variables properly. It's easy to lose track of s, b, f, i, etc.

Comment: @Ben thanks so much for this great info... regards the 'The equivalent of a js Float32Array is float[]' - im not sure if this is different in Unity, but in Unity when I Debug.Log the values of the example I gave when converted to floats they are much shorter- i.e. 0.822689414024353 ends up as 0.8226894, but the original values when I use an  'Implicitly typed' array to create the array come out the same and the array itself gets set to be a double array rather than a float array. So is the C# equivalent of a Float32Array actually a double array or am confusing something else somewhere?

Comment: All numbers in JavaScript are double (Float64), there are no integer types (in theory). A javascript integer is a float whose exponent is zero.

When you store them in a Float32Array they are converted to Float32 (with loss of precision). When you store them in an Int32Array they are converted to Int32 (without loss of precision, if the number is in the range of an Int32).

When you retrieve them from the array, they are converted back to Float64.

(Caveat: the engine may optimise them and use integers internally for some purposes, but the effect is *as if* they are all doubles)

Comment: Meanwhile, in C#, a floating point constant is automatically a double, unless you use the suffix `f` to indicate a float, like so: `var test = new [] { 0.1f, 0.2f }`.

Comment: Ok so does that mean that even though the Debug.Log is logging the numbers shorter in the float[] they are actually longer in memory? Or just that, for the example numbers I gave, I should use double[]?

Comment: No, I am saying if you did the debug log in JavaScript, the `Float32Array[n]` would **also** have less precision - they will both be rounded. Try it in F12 tools.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear- the Debug.Log I am referring to is in C# (Unity) the console.log for the javascript values that the function I want to convert are now at the end of my original post

Comment: So regards the 'Float32Array' = float[] in C# issue I am just trying to clarify why it is that C# float[] numbers end up being shorter than C# double[] numbers (I mean I know that C# float is 7 digits and C# double is 15-16 but I don't know why everyone is saying I should use float[] given my originally posted numbers)- I dont want to offend anyone, but might it not be the case that, given the numbers I originally mentioned double[] is what I need? I'm not trying to be clever or insulting, I'm just trying to understand

Comment: @DavidO'Sullivan You want your Int and Float sizes to be the same for the algorithm to work.  Otherwise, your first float64-view element in the buffer would be created from the first 2 int32-view elements etc [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Comment: @James the function works in javascript, sorry if I am mis-understanding you. You can see what I am using if for here http://yousitepro.com/js-objectdetect/examples/example_image.htm So I know the js works, and I have recreated most of it in C# the thing I am stuck on is how to do the DataView thing that James mentions above with a C# array...

Comment: Having read your code it is clear that: you care about sharing the arraybuffer. Your existing code accesses the array buffer both as Int32 and as Float32 arrays. So the answer here is not suitable for you. In order to directly covert the code - as opposed to re-implementing the algorithm more efficiently - you will need to find an implementation of ArrayBuffer/Float32Array/Int32Array.